# Stripe API for multiple bank cards, with Stripe.Net as a client

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe as a payment handler and a C# `Stripe.Net` library to handle Stripe connection.

My client want's to accept payments in more than one currency, but doesn't want to use Stripe currency conversions.

I found [this](https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-does-stripe-handle-currency-conversion) link and it says:

> Businesses based in certain countries can add multiple bank accounts to their Stripe account. For any payments in currencies that are supported by one of your banks, we’ll deposit funds without conversion.

The only question is - does Stripe support payments with those currencies automatically?

Let's say that I have to cards attached, one in EUR and one in USD. Then I send a payment via my API: 10 EUR. Does Stripe automatically find out that I have an Euro card attached and transfer funds to it, or do I have to explicitly state in my API, that funds should be transferred to that concrete card?

I'm only using a dev account for now, so I can't check it and I found no information about that on the Internet.

Comment: This is not really a coding question and more a question about Stripe's system and currency conversion. You should reach out to support directly: https://support.stripe.com/email. To answer your question, this would never work no, you charge a specific card and you decide which one yourself.

Comment: Not a coding/technical question